# how to excute command towards many files automatically in windows CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Here is the command (which could be excuted within Windows CMD):

```
makeblastdb -in mydb.fsa -parse_seqids -dbtype nucl
```

I want to excute this command to many files one after one or at the same time,
such as:

```
makeblastdb -in mydb.fsa1 -parse_seqids -dbtype nucl
makeblastdb -in mydb.fsa2 -parse_seqids -dbtype nucl
makeblastdb -in mydb.fsa3 -parse_seqids -dbtype nucl
makeblastdb -in mydb.fsa4 -parse_seqids -dbtype nucl
makeblastdb -in mydb.fsa5 -parse_seqids -dbtype nucl
...
```

It is impossible to do it manully because I get 60,000 files. Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: probably not the only duplicate, but that one can be easily adapted to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`For`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) command.

```
for %%file in (directory) DO (makeblastdb -in %%file -parse_seqids -dbtype nucl)
```

If you only want specific files, use wildcards to build a mask

```
for %%file in (directory\mydb.fsa*) DO (makeblastdb -in %%file -parse_seqids -dbtype nucl)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what i'm searching for.